# regarding the correct approach for comparing two character arrays imported from csv file

Tags: r

I have a csv file, the first row is plain texts, and other rows are numerical values. I need to read this first row into a character vector.

```
matrixR = read.csv("testR.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE)
matrixR[1,]
    V1     V2      V3    V4  V5  
academic adagio admiral allan alt
```

The above is the first row. Besides this file, I also have another csv file with the same format as the first file. I read it as follows:

```
matrixJ = read.csv("testJ.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE)
matrixJ[1,]
    V1     V2      V3    V4  V5  
academic  admiral abc alt bd
```

For each entry in the first row of matrixR, I need to check whether it also exists in the first row of matrixJ.  If it exists, I need to capture its corresponding position in the first row of matrixJ.  This is how I did

```
which(matrixR[1,2]==matrixJ[1,])
Error in matrixR[1, 2] == matrixJ[1, ] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
  In which(matrixR[1, 2] == matrixJ[1, ]) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for "=="
```

What should be the correct way to implement this kind of functionality? Thanks.

The following is what I did as suggested, looks like the result is still not correct.

```
> matrixR = as.matrix(read.csv("testWeightR1.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE))
> matrixJ =as.matrix(read.csv("testWeightJ1.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE))
> which(unlist(matrixR[1,]) %in% unlist(matrixJ[1,]))
   [1] 1 2 3 4 6
```

The information for matrixR and matrixJ is as follows:

> matrixR[1,]
>           V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6 
>         "academic"   "adagio"  "admiral"    "allan"     "test"  "admiral" 
>   matrixJ[1,]
>           V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6 
>         "academic"   "adagio"  "admiral"    "allan"      "alt"      "ans" 
>   dput(head(matrixR))

```
 structure(c("academic", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "adagio", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "admiral", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "allan", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "test", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "admiral", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))
 > dput(head(matrixJ))
 structure(c("academic", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "adagio", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "admiral", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "allan", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "alt", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "ans", 
 "0", "1", "1", "0", "1"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want using `%in% with`which`:

```
which(matrixR[1,] %in% matrixJ[1,])
```

The `==` is for when you're comparing against one item.  When you're comparing against a vector use `%in%`

**EDIT...**

If it's a matrix try:

```
which(unlist(matrixR[1,]) %in% unlist(matrixJ[1,]))
```

**EDIT 2...**

Now that you've provided the reproducible example it's much easier to give you more exact advice:

```
matrixR  <-
 structure(c("academic", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "adagio", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "admiral", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "allan", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "test", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "admiral", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))

matrixJ <-
 structure(c("academic", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "adagio", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "admiral", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "allan", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "alt", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "ans", 
 "0", "1", "1", "0", "1"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))

#> matrixR 
#     V1         V2       V3        V4      V5     V6       
#[1,] "academic" "adagio" "admiral" "allan" "test" "admiral"
#[2,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "2"    "0"      
#[3,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "2"    "0"      
#[4,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "1"    "0"      
#[5,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "1"    "0"      
#[6,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "1"    "0"      
#> 
#> matrixJ 
#     V1         V2       V3        V4      V5    V6   
#[1,] "academic" "adagio" "admiral" "allan" "alt" "ans"
#[2,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "2"   "0"  
#[3,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "2"   "1"  
#[4,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "1"   "1"  
#[5,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "1"   "0"  
#[6,] "0"        "0"      "0"       "0"     "1"   "1"  

which(matrixR[1, ] %in% matrixJ[1, ])

#> which(matrixR[1, ] %in% matrixJ[1, ])
#[1] 1 2 3 4 6
```

Note this is the response I originally gave you unless you're looking for something else:

Comment: I tried > which(matrixR[1,1] %in% matrixJ[1,])
integer(0)  I was hoping to get the position of "academic", which should be 1

Comment: See my edit, may I also suggest a minimal reproducible example, maybe `dput(head(matrixR))` and `dput(head(matrixJ))`, so it's easier to understand the structure of the problem.

Comment: I have posted the result, looks like the result is still not correct.